# How to configure publishers programmatically

Tags: aem, day-cq

For disaster recovery purposes we have to invent mechanism for automated deploying CQ instance. It must setup replication agents automatically, getting agents configuration from property file and deploy them to CQ automatically, without any human intervention.
Have somebody any experience how to do that?

I tried to make nodes for replication agents by path: /etc/replication/agents.author
But seems it does not work.

One more issue is how to store password field. CQ saves **hash** in the property 'transportPassword' (like {8daa5f84c1c8067bab760cb93b8de6642c9e67ebda900ce5902b9910165fb9388558d4b0579b8c496695563eda60a25d}). May be somebody knows algorithm?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post your cURL command here. There are several potential gotchya's, but it can be done.

Comment: I am making it inside CQ using JCR session (not through 'curl' command). Special bundle during start process reads properties from file and deploy publishers relying on the information in the file. Seems it works. I will describe how I managed with it after all tests are passed.

Comment: I found the decision.
To setup new environment from scratch (M-authors, N-publishers, K-dispatchers) we use next technique.
Configurations for replication agent on authors, flash agents on publishers, reverse replication agents on publishers we store in special external file. Installed from scratch author ...

Comment: ...author and publisher instances are copied to archive. This archive is deployed to each corresponding instance machine. After that agent-configuration file is copied to corresponding instance. Starting instances. After instances are started, maven builds special disaster recovery bundle, which get agent configurations from the file and creates replication agents. Password hashes are already present in that files, because we can always get it from original instances. After all processes are ...

Comment: ... are finished - we build our content packages and bundles to the corresponding instances. Eventually we have fully automated environment deployment. It already has been tested and it works on our project.

Answer (score 0):

Password looks like it came from Crypto Support Service

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a content package of the replication agents?  You could programmatically upload & install the content package.  I would confess to not knowing off the top of my head if the hased password changes from instance to instance.

Comment: Thank you. I found when you try to upload content with replication agents configurations (/etc/replication/agents.author) from a cq-package (trough CQ Package Manager), replication will not work. But when you make nodes programmatically (trough jcr session), it works. 
For password-cache generation purpose you can use cq. Password is predetermined, so you can take hash from the replication agent node and use it.